# Is it possible to create Noobaa bucket without creating ObjectBucketClaim(OBC)?

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket, object-storage, noobaa-data-services

I am able to create noobaa bucket by creating OBC as shown below:

```
apiVersion: objectbucket.io/v1alpha1
kind: ObjectBucketClaim
metadata:
  name: my-obc1
spec:
  storageClassName: noobaa-test.noobaa.io
  bucketName: my-bucket
  additionalConfig: {}
```

Above OBC will create a noobaa bucket `my-bucket`.
But is there any way we can create noobaa bucket directly without having to create OBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to create buckets in noobaa other than OBC:

1. You can use the UI - open with `noobaa ui`.
2. You can use the simple command - `noobaa bucket create <name>`.
3. You can use the internal API - `noobaa api bucket create_bucket '{ "name": "<name>" ... }'` (see here the [json schema of this api params](https://github.com/noobaa/noobaa-core/blob/v5.3.0/src/api/bucket_api.js#L17-L53))
4. You can use S3 - take the endpoint and credentials from `noobaa status`.

Thanks! Guy

Comment: But how to set `backingstore` for noobaa bucket created using above mentioned methods?

Comment: NooBaa BackingStores can be used in BucketClass to specify placementPolicy and then used to set as the bucketclass on OBC. See the following doc links: 
- https://github.com/noobaa/noobaa-operator/blob/master/doc/backing-store-crd.md
- https://github.com/noobaa/noobaa-operator/blob/master/doc/bucket-class-crd.md
- https://github.com/noobaa/noobaa-operator/blob/master/doc/obc-provisioner.md

Comment: But my question is specific to noobaa bucket created without OBC. 
Actually I am provisioning noobaa bucket using https://github.com/IBM/ibmcloud-object-storage-plugin (out of the box, volume plugin). So in this case, how we can attach backingstore to Noobaa bucket so that when we mount noobaa bucket as PVC inside pod and write data to it, the data should go to some backing store of user choice.

Comment: @MayankSachan This can be done with create_bucket api call, but first we need to create a tiering policy to refer to that backing store like the operator is doing here for OBCs - https://github.com/noobaa/noobaa-operator/blob/1cf4cbabde9a6ab4024421054e8ee5e48735b704/pkg/obc/provisioner.go#L291-L360.  May I suggest we move this discussion to a github issue?

Comment: please feel free to open github issue.

Comment: Could you please share `noobaa api` command to create Tier policy and then bucket creation using already created tier policy.
Assume that a backingstore with name `default-backing-store` is already present

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue as I want to be able to create a bucket and for it to have a Tier Policy and Tier associated with it which will point it to the correct backingstore which I had already created, just like you can in the management UI but from the command line. This is what I came up with:-

```
#!/bin/bash
BUCKET_NAME="my_bucket"
BACKINGSTORE="my_backing_store"

NOW=$(gdate +%s)
TIER_NAME=$(printf "%s.%x" ${BUCKET_NAME} ${NOW})
TIER_POLICY_NAME=$(printf "%s.%d" ${BUCKET_NAME} 1)
noobaa -n noobaa api tier create_tier "{\"name\": \"${TIER_NAME}\", \"attached_pools\": [\"${BACKINGSTORE}\"], \"data_placement\": \"SPREAD\"}"
noobaa -n noobaa api tiering_policy create_policy "{\"name\": \"${TIER_POLICY_NAME}\", \"tiers\": [{\"order\": 1, \"tier\": \"${TIER_NAME}\"}]}"
noobaa -n noobaa api bucket create_bucket "{\"name\": \"${BUCKET_NAME}\", \"tiering\": \"${TIER_POLICY_NAME}\"}"
```